# Is the use of '@' in PHP an out-of-the-box option?

Tags: php

Is preceding function calls with the at-sign (@) a standard out-of-the-box option or do I need to enable it in `php.ini`?

I am getting the following server error in the error_log file:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '@' in /htdocs/www/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php on line 467`

Here is line 467 in the php script file:
`if (@extension_loaded('mbstring') && !empty(@ini_get('mbstring.func_overload'))) {`

If it needs to be enabled in php.ini where might that be?

Thanks.

Amended

Here's the code block that throws the error:

```
/**
 * check for errors occurred while loading configuration
 * this check is done here after loading language files to present errors in locale
 */
$GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->checkPermissions();
$GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->checkErrors();

/**
 * As we try to handle charsets by ourself, mbstring overloads just
 * break it, see bug 1063821.
 *
 * We specifically use empty here as we are looking for anything else than
 * empty value or 0.
 */
if (@extension_loaded('mbstring') && !empty(@ini_get('mbstring.func_overload'))) {
    PMA_fatalError(
        __(
            'You have enabled mbstring.func_overload in your PHP '
            . 'configuration. This option is incompatible with phpMyAdmin '
            . 'and might cause some data to be corrupted!'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: The `@` just says dont report errors and is an out-of-the-box feature

Comment: Why do you need to use the @ at all?

Comment: Ok, thanks @RiggsFolly ... I knew what it represented as I've used it in the past....I just did not know if it needed to be enabled in php.ini. Now how to solve the error :)

Comment: You might be missing a `;`, `}`, or `)` before the `@`?

Comment: I'm not using it @Andreas -- phpMyAdmin is (out-of-its-box)

Comment: I amended the OQ with more of phpMyAdmin's code block @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [PHP: empty - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

> Prior to PHP 5.5, `empty()` only supports variables; anything else
>   will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not
>   work: `empty(trim($name))`. Instead, use `trim($name) == false`.

So the `@` is not a variable and generates the error.  If you remove the `@` from the `empty()` call as:

```
if (@extension_loaded('mbstring') && !empty(ini_get('mbstring.func_overload'))) {}
```

It will still generate the following parse error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

PHP 5.3.3 was released 7 years ago and hasn't been supported in over 3 years. If unable to upgrade (recommended) use [phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.20](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/).

Comment: Does anyone know which version of phpMyAdmin would be the very last version to work with PHP 5.3.3 ?

Comment: PHP 5.3.3 was released 7 years ago and hasn't been supported in over 3 years.

Comment: If unable to upgrade (recommended) use phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.20 https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

Comment: I selected this as the answer because the root cause in my OQ related to the version of phpMyAdmin being installed was not compatible with my server's version of PHP. So I installed `phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.20` per @AbraCadaver's answer and I solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to your version of PhpMyAdmin, you need to run PHP > 5.5.

See : https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

> Current version compatible with PHP 5.5 to 7.1 and MySQL 5.5 and
>   newer.

That's why you got an error.

Comment: awesome that fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

The error control operator `@` is part of the language. You can not disable it.

The parse error indicates a malformed source.

> Note: The @-operator works only on expressions. A simple rule of thumb is: if you can take the value of something, you can prepend the @ operator to it. For instance, you can prepend it to variables, function and include calls, constants, and so forth. You cannot prepend it to function or class definitions, or conditional structures such as if and foreach, and so forth

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer was posted before source code was present. Please vote for AbraCadaver's answer.

Comment: This is a good answer.  But, to explain what `@` actually does: it temporarily sets the error reporting level to 0 for the expression. If the expression triggers an error, whatever error handler you're using will be called, but with an error level of 0.  If you haven't specified an error handler, out-of-the-box php will just stay quiet about it.

Comment: Ah @AbraCadaver -- we are running PHP 5.3.3. So are you saying I am getting this error because phpMyAdmin's version is no longer compatible with our PHP instance?

Comment: It depends on your phpmyadmin version ?

Comment: Latest / greatest v4.7.3 @VincentDecaux -- do you happen to know which version of phpMyAdmin would be the very last version to work with PHP 5.3.3 ?